# Private plane without a flight number - is it illegal?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-numbers

[This article](https://eu.detroitnews.com/story/news/local/detroit-city/2022/05/06/detroit-rapper-42-dugg-feds-reveal-new-manhunt-details/9672939002/) from the Detroit News describes the arrest of a rapper on various charges, which aren't relevant here.  However, there are a couple of aviation-related statements in it that seem to imply additional offences were committed:

> Agents soon discovered the private jet did not have an assigned flight number.

> Agents asked airport security to confirm [the accused] was aboard the flight. They checked the manifest but [the accused] was not listed among the passengers.

> "He has access to a private plane with a pilot willing to fly an unnumbered flight where [the accused] is not included on the flight’s manifest,” [the detective] said. “That’s not an accident. That’s not a happenstance.”

Has the pilot (or anyone else) actually committed an offence in these circumstances?  If so, which particular provisions of the FAA regulations have been violated?  Or is it just the newspaper (or the police) introducing irrelevant material to make the accused's conduct seem worse than it actually is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Flight number.** Flights operated in the United States are not required to operate using an airline callsign and flight number. All aircraft *are* required to have a **registration number**, similar to a license plate. Flights may use a flight number, which could be assigned to any aircraft, or may identify themselves using the aircraft registration number, which is unique to the aircraft. There is no legal concern here.

---

**Passenger manifest.** To protect the flying public, the FAA regulates operators who carry passengers for hire. There are several different sets of regulations which may apply to an operation. More information can be found elsewhere online, for example [this article from Pilot Institute](https://pilotinstitute.com/part-91-vs-121-vs-135/). However, as a brief overview:

- 14 CFR Part 121 applies to scheduled air carrier operations—you would recognize operations carried out by "mainline" airlines such as American and "low-cost" airlines like Sprit, as well as "regional" airlines like Endeavor or Republic. These regulations are most restrictive.
- 14 CFR Part 135 applies to "commuter operations and on-demand operations," commonly known as "charters." These would generally be smaller twin-turbojet aircraft which are operated for the benefit of anyone who buys a flight from Point A to Point B; Executive Jet Management is operated under Part 135. Some airlines, for example Cape Air, also operate smaller turbo-propeller flights under Part 135.
- 14 CFR Part 91K applies to "fractional ownership" flights. This is a system in which customers technically purchase *part ownership* in an aircraft or fleet of aircraft, and therefore have the right to (additionally) purchase a certain amount of flight time per year. NetJets operates aircraft under Part 91K. These regulations are less restrictive.

A "private aircraft" as described in the article would likely be operated under Part 91K or Part 135.

For Part 91K, [*14 CFR § 91.1027 - Recordkeeping*](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.1027) applies:

> **(c)** Each program manager is responsible for the preparation and accuracy of a load manifest in duplicate containing information concerning the loading of the aircraft. The manifest must be prepared before each takeoff and must include -
>
> 1. The number of passengers;
> 2. The total weight of the loaded aircraft;
> 3. The maximum allowable takeoff weight for that flight;
> 4. The center of gravity limits;
> 5. The center of gravity of the loaded aircraft, except that the actual center of gravity need not be computed if the aircraft is loaded according to a loading schedule or other approved method that ensures that the center of gravity of the loaded aircraft is within approved limits. In those cases, an entry must be made on the manifest indicating that the center of gravity is within limits according to a loading schedule or other approved method;
> 6. The registration number of the aircraft or flight number;
> 7. The origin and destination; and
> 8. Identification of crewmembers and their crew position assignments.

You will note that **identification** of the passengers is not required; however **enumeration** of the passengers is.

For Part 135 operators, [*14 CFR § 135.63 - Recordkeeping requirements*](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/135.63) applies; the requirements are exactly the same as 91.1027 above.

Regardless of whether the flight was operated under Part 91K or Part 135, the person in question should have been accounted for on the aircraft load manifest. However in neither case was he required to be named on the manifest.

Comment: Thanks!  From the rest of the article, the flight appears to have been a perfectly legitimate Part 135 operation, with no sinister overtones.